# Keyboard shifted after adding AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I recently added AndEngine to my android studio project. And strangely all the symbols changed places (like { and } are now another keys). I dont understand what happened but is bothering not being able to find the = symbol!
Outside android its normal, so what is the problem?

Comment: what keyboard? system or did you make it yourself? any code?

Comment: the letters i phisically press on my keyboard are different from the ones that are typed.And i didnt even started coding!